# I am using @PathVariable from springframework. When I try to return view page name from controller, I get 404 error

Tags: java, spring, annotations, path-variables

I am using spring mvc(version:4.1.5.RELEASE). I have added new controller in my project and trying to use @PathVariable annotation. As I add this annotation I get 404 error of my jsp template view page. If I remove @PathVariable annotation and {id} from @RequestMapping path, code works properly. Can someone please help me whats wrong?

```
dispatcher-servlet.xml
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="WEB-INF/views/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
```

my new controller

```
@Controller
public class MoviesController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/movie/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String moviesDetails(@PathVariable(value="id")
                                String id, ModelMap map) {
        System.out.println(id);
        map.addAttribute("movieId", id);
        return "moviesDetails";
    }
}
```

---

link where i am adding id is like below.

### a href="movie/${movie.id}">${movie.movieName}

HTTP Status 404 - /shcm/movie/WEB-INF/views/moviesDetails.jsp

moviesDetails.jsp file already exists in WEB-INF/views path

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change in controller :

```
 @GetMapping("/movie/{id}")
 public String moviesDetails(@PathVariable
                                String id, ModelMap map) {
        System.out.println(id);
        map.addAttribute("movieId", id);
        return "moviesDetails";
    }
```

And in web.xml :

```
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"></property>
```

Answer (score -1):

Change

@PathVariable(value="id") String id

to

@PathVariable("id") String id